# Reverse for 'newsdate' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['newsdate/(?P<year>[0-9]+)$']

Tags: python, django

I was trying Django Tutorials.
I have used a navbar template and used it in base html file. And all other pages are inheriting that base file. But when on linking the newdate(name given in urls.py) I am getting this error

```
NoReverseMatch at /newsdate/2020

Reverse for 'newsdate' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['newsdate/(?P<year>[0-9]+)$']
```

I visited http://127.0.0.1:8000/newsdate/2020
My database with contain one entry with date 2020,
The selection of objects from database is getting completed as  **print("lol",artice_list)** prints the item matching from database.

Error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /newsdate/2020

Reverse for 'newsdate' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['newsdate/(?P<year>[0-9]+)$']

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/newsdate/2020
Django Version:     3.0
Exception Type:     NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    

Reverse for 'newsdate' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['newsdate/(?P<year>[0-9]+)$']

Exception Location:     /home/rishabh/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py in _reverse_with_prefix, line 676
Python Executable:  /home/rishabh/anaconda3/bin/python
Python Version:     3.7.4
Python Path:    

['/home/rishabh/Documents/DjangoWorks/Learning/src',
 '/home/rishabh/anaconda3/lib/python37.zip',
 '/home/rishabh/anaconda3/lib/python3.7',
 '/home/rishabh/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload',
 '/home/rishabh/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages']

Server time:    Sun, 26 Apr 2020 17:11:09 +0000
Error during template rendering

In template /home/rishabh/Documents/DjangoWorks/Learning/src/templates/navbar.html, error at line 6
Reverse for 'newsdate' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['newsdate/(?P<year>[0-9]+)$']
1   <nav>
2       <ul>
3           <li><a href="{% url 'home' %}">Home</a></li>
4           <li><a href="{% url 'news' %}">News</a></li>
5           <li><a href="{% url 'contact' %}">Contact</a></li>
6           <li><a href="{% url 'newsdate' %}">News by Date</a></li>
7       </ul>
8   </nav>
```

Traceback:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/newsdate/2020

Django Version: 3.0
Python Version: 3.7.4
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'NewsApp']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']


Template error:
In template /home/rishabh/Documents/DjangoWorks/Learning/src/templates/navbar.html, error at line 6
   Reverse for 'newsdate' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['newsdate/(?P<year>[0-9]+)$']
   1 : <nav>
   2 :     <ul>
   3 :         <li><a href="{% url 'home' %}">Home</a></li>
   4 :         <li><a href="{% url 'news' %}">News</a></li>
   5 :         <li><a href="{% url 'contact' %}">Contact</a></li>
   6 :         <li><a href=" {% url 'newsdate' %} ">News by Date</a></li>
   7 :     </ul>
   8 : </nav>

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/rishabh/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/rishabh/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/rishabh/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/rishabh/Documents/DjangoWorks/Learning/src/NewsApp/views.py", line 26, in NewsDate
    return render(request,'newsdate.html',context)
  File "/home/rishabh/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py", line 19, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
  File "/home/rishabh/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 62, in render_to_string
    return template.render(context, request)
  File "/home/rishabh/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "/home/rishabh/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 171, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "/home/rishabh/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 163, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/home/rishabh/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 936, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/home/rishabh/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/home/rishabh/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 150, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "/home/rishabh/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 163, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/home/rishabh/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 936, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/home/rishabh/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/home/rishabh/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 188, in render
    return template.render(context)
  File "/home/rishabh/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 173, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "/home/rishabh/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 163, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/home/rishabh/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 936, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/home/rishabh/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/home/rishabh/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 443, in render
    url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=current_app)
  File "/home/rishabh/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/base.py", line 87, in reverse
    return iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs))
  File "/home/rishabh/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 676, in _reverse_with_prefix
    raise NoReverseMatch(msg)

Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /newsdate/2020
Exception Value: Reverse for 'newsdate' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['newsdate/(?P<year>[0-9]+)$']
```

navbar.html

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="{% url 'home' %}">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="{% url 'news' %}">News</a></li>
        <li><a href="{% url 'contact' %}">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="{% url 'newsdate' %}">News by Date</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

base.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>{% block title%} {% endblock %}</title>

    {% include 'navbar.html' %}
</head>
<body>
    {% block body%} {% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

newsdate.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block title %}Date Wise News{% endblock %}
{% block body %}
<h2>News for year {{year}}</h2>

{% for article in atricle_list %}
<h3>{{article.title}}</h3>
<b>{{article.author}}</b>
<b>{{article.pub_date}}</b>
<p>{{article.description}}</p>

{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import News
from .models import SportNews
# Create your views here.
def news(request):
    context={
        "state":News.objects.get(id=1),
        }
    return render(request,'news.html',context)

def home(request):
    return render(request,'home.html')

def contact(request):
    return render(request,'contact.html')

def NewsDate(request,year):
    artice_list=News.objects.filter(pub_date__year=year)
    context={
        'year':year,
        'artice_list':artice_list,
    }
    print("lol",artice_list)

    return render(request,'newsdate.html',context)
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import news,contact,home,NewsDate

urlpatterns = [
    path('news/',news,name='news'),
    path('contact/',contact,name='contact'),
    path('newsdate/<int:year>',NewsDate,name='newsdate'),
    path('', home,name='home'),
]
```

Comment: Well it expects a year int he `{% url %}` for `newsdate`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `path` for the `newsdate` view has an `<int:year>` parameter. So you need to provide one, for example:

```
<li><a href="{% url 'newsdate' 2020 %}">News by Date</a></li>
```